# Can't access PowerShell class in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, reference

I am migrating an existing ASP.NET (Webpages) project to an ASP.NET MVC one and I'm facing a little issue. I don't know if I lack information about PowerShell but in the original project, there is a reference to `System.Management.Automation.dll` to be able to use PowerShell and other classes. Now I added the reference (once by going to the direct location: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll`

I also tried through the NuGet package`System.Management.Automation`. My problem is that I can't seem to use and initiate the `PowerShell` object itself so I could call PowerShell.Create() for example. I can access `PSObject`, `Runspace`, `WSMANConnectionInfo` but just not the `PowerShell` class, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Highly recommend you use whatever native methods you are trying to invoke.  Powershell from the web is seldom a good idea.

Comment: Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for samples on using `PowerShell`

Comment: @No Refunds No Returns i have to its not an option, we are using it to communicate with Microsoft MSOL services & O365 so this is the only option for what we have to achieve. Do you mean Win32 API's calls with native (not sure about how to understand the sentence)?

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto, thank you but i didn't ask for examples of how to use PS, i have a fully running WebApp the only issue i am having is the usage of the "PowerShell" object itself, its not available for some reason but i do have the ref to System.Management.Automation and the ability to use PSObject & Runspace so i am either missing another ref or something is different from a ASP webpage project compared to a ASP MVC project ... (i tried all available NuGet Packages just to be sure but still not able to use the PowerShell instance.

Comment: What .net version are you compiling against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Camilo Terevinto, The original project where it is working is on 4.5, mine (the new one) is on 4.6.X, i changed it but it didn't solved it (i cleaned & rebuild the solution as well) but what i did was i created a new MVC project and compared the references in there with my MVC project and when removing everything till was the same as a freshly created one, i added the ref back to the System.Management.Automation.dll and then it worked, there was 1 ref called 'PowerShell' in project references so my guess is that this was causing the issue, strange i didn't have the "ambiguity" message from VS though ... Thank you both for your replies!

Good day/evening !
Kind regards